# GitHub Codespaces: can't open file explorer at top-level directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-codespaces

When you start a Codespace, it puts you in `/workspaces/repoName`, both in the terminal and the sidebar file explorer.

From the terminal, you can `cd /` into the top level directory, and do command-line stuff.

But the file explorer can't seem to navigate "up" directories past `workspaces/repoName`.

From desktop VSCode, you can connect to a GitHub Codespace and `cd / && code .` to open a new editor in the top level directory, but it's clunky and opens a separate editor.

Is there a way to set the GUI file explorer to open at the top level directory?

Answer (score 1):

Add `?folder=/` to the end of the Codespace URI to open it in the root directory. This makes the URI look like `https://username-repo-random.github.dev/?folder=/`.

Alternatively, you can use the integrated terminal and run `cd / && code .` from there to open a new tab with the Codespace in the root directory. The opened Codespace will have `?folder=/` in the URI, so this is effectively equivalent to the other way I described.